# How can I check if a file exists using Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like emacs to mark files that are generated as read-only when they're opened.  The part of the puzzle that I'm missing is how to check if a file "exists".  I currently have the following:

```
;;
;; get file extension
;;
(defun get-ext (file-name)
  (car (cdr (split-string file-name "\\."))))

;; 
;; get the base name of the file
;;
(defun base-name (file-name)
  (car (split-string file-name "\\.")))

;;
;; if an 'lzz' file exists for this header, mark it as read only
;;
(defun mark-read-only ()
  (if (string= (get-ext (cur-file)) "h")
      (if ( ??file-exists??? (concat (base-name (cur-file)) ".lzz") )
          (toggle-read-only))))
```

What can I use for "???file-exists???"?

Once I find this, I'll add "mark-read-only" to the appropriate hook (which I think is the find-file-hook).

**BACKGROUND**

We use [lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) as a code generator to simplify our C/C++ development process.  Briefly, lzz takes a single input file (which looks very like C/C++) and generates header and source files as appropriate.

By default, lzz includes #line directives so that the debugger points to the original source and not the generated source, however, to reduce compilation dependencies we normally disable these directives in header files.  The result is that when debugging templates or inline functions, the debugger normally points to the generated header file and not the original source file.

This is not a big deal, however, recently I've found that when debugging I'll make a quick modification to the displayed file and then I'll rebuild.  Of course this normally means that the change I made disappears because the file I edited is generated and so the changes are "blown away" during the library rebuild.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to everyone for their help and comments.  A special thanks to [cobbal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73681/cobbal) for pointing out the correct function to use.

Here's the resulting code (with updates based on the other comments here too):

```
(defun cur-file ()
  "Return the filename (without directory) of the current buffer"
  (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
  )

(defun mark-generated-as-read-only ()
  "Mark generated source files as read only.
Mark generated files (lzz or gz) read only to avoid accidental updates."
  (if
      (or (string= (file-name-extension (cur-file)) "h")
          (string= (file-name-extension (cur-file)) "cpp"))
      (cond
       (
        (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension (cur-file)) ".lzz"))
        (toggle-read-only))
       (
        (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension (cur-file)) ".gz") )
        (toggle-read-only))
       )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Instead of putting comments above your functions, in Elisp, you can write them in the first line of a function declaration. It called the "docstring". See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Documentation-Basics.html

Comment: Note: your first two functions come with Emacs, they are named 'file-name-extension and 'file-name-sans-extension

Answer (score 111, accepted):

try `file-exists-p`

"Return t if file filename exists (whether or not you can read it.)".

Note that it's not spesific to  files and works for directories too.

Comment: Why doesn't this function appear when I do a "C-H a" appros search for it?  I tried searching for file and going through the results for 'exists', and there are no matches at all for exists!

Comment: yeah, I tried looking for 'exists' that way, then found the function 'find-file-existing' in files.el, opened that up and found the file-exists-p. don't know why it doesn't show up under C-H a

Comment: file-exists-p doesn't show up under "C-H a" because it's not an "interactive" function. It should show up under "M-x apropos" though.

Comment: Which is exactly why I have this in my .emacs (define-key help-map "a" 'apropos)    That way "C-h a" finds looks through all symbols for me.

Comment: Speaking of file-exists-p, this function is also a way to check if a directory exists. There is no separate directory-exists-p.

Comment: Yes there is, it's called `file-directory-p`.

Comment: @Trey You can also set `apropos-do-all` to non-nil to get `apropos-command` (default "C-h a" binding) to search non-interactive functions

Comment: use the prefix command with `C-h a` to also get non interactive functions. `C-u C-h a`

Answer (score 17):

- Depending on what you need, you might want `file-readable-p` instead of `file-exists-p`.
- Apropos will only get you so far.  [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) provides [apropos completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions) and [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) which let you find help easily for command, function, variable, etc. names that match subparts in an arbitrary order (is it `file-exists-p` or `exists-file-p`?).

Answer (score 8):

Use [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el), modern library for file and directory manipulation. You can use [`f-exists?`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-exists-path), `f-file?`, `f-directory?` and many other predicates. The library is better than standard functions, because it's every file related function you'll ever need under one namespace.

Comment: That's nice, but these function names don't follow standard lisp convention (...-p)